# How to convert string to Time in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a string of like `120` i want to convert into time like `02:00(hh:mm)`.
Actual :

```
120
```

Expected:

```
02:00.
```

so, please suggest result.

Comment: Just time - then the best is to use moment.js

Comment: yes only want time in javascript

Comment: How come 120 is 2:00?

Comment: @SalmanA - you think it might be seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ow418gLc/1/

```
var value = 120
var hours = pad(Math.floor(value / 60));
var minutes = pad(value % 60);

function pad(n){
    n = n.toString();
    n = n.length < 0 ? n: ("0" + n);
    return n;
};

console.log(hours + ":" + minutes);
```

output:

```
02:00
```

EDIT:
There is a small bug in the padding above and I converted this to a real function.

```
function convertMinutesToTime(minutes) {
    function pad(n) {
        n = n.toString();
        n = n.length < 2 ? ("0" + n) : n;
        return n;
    };
    var paddedHours = pad(Math.floor(minutes / 60));
    var paddedMinutes = pad(minutes % 60);

    return paddedHours + ":" + paddedMinutes
}

console.log(convertMinutesToTime(120));
```

Comment: it gives 00:020 expected- 02:00.

Comment: Does the edit version work for you? Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ow418gLc/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var mins = 120;

var h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
var t = (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + ("00" + mins % 60).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to do three steps:

1. Turn a string into a number:

   ```
   var number = parseInt(string, 10);
   ```
2. Create a `Date` from a number of seconds:

   ```
   var date = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 0, 0, seconds);
   ```
3. Create a formatted date string from a `Date`. For that, you might like to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and do:

   ```
   var formatted = moment(date).format('hh:ss');
   ```